# Is possible to add a record in between the others in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database in mysql, and a table called Animals, I use this condition to add news records.

```
public function create()
{
   $animals = Animals::all();
   $last_animal_id = collect($animals)->last();

   if ($last_animal_id->id == $last_animal_id->id) {

     $last_animal_id->id = $last_animal_id->id + 1;

   } else {

      return false;
    }

   return view('animal.create-animals')->with('last_animal_id', $last_animal_id);
}
```

**I work in laravel and php**, and that is my controller **'AnimalsController'**, the condition add +1 to the last id that is registered in the table.

For example, I have 4 records and I delete the last record, without my condition, after I have added a new record the new record will take the value 6.

And that is the reason that I add manually new records, with this condition, the condition find the last id, and add +1 to the last id, not +2 if I not have this condition. **Not directly**, I pass the value to an input and then I send the form in my view.

Is possible to add +1 id in the table, if I delete a record in the middle, or before the last record? As the following example explains:

**Table Animals**

```
/*NOTE: The field 'id' HAVE THE FOLLOWING ATTRIBUTES:
AUTO_INCREMENT, IS 'NOT NULL','PRIMARY KEY', AND HIS TYPE IS 'INT'*/

id|name   |class

1 |Dog    |Mammal
2 |Cat    |Mammal
3 |Sparrow|Bird
4 |Whale  |Mammal
5 |Frog   |Amphibian
6 |Snake  |Reptile
```

Then I delete the **`id`, `2`,** and **`3`.**

In addition to the condition that already exists, I would like to create another condition that allows to add new records among the others, only if there are missing records in between of others.

Using the previous example:

I said that I will delete the id 2 and 3 right? The new condition must allow to create again the records with the **`id 2`** and **`3`** between the records with the **`id 1`** and **`4`**.

If I delete another record the condition must perform the same function. Certainly replacing the records with corresponding **`id`** that were previously deleted.

> For more details: I use a form to create new animals to the table Animals, previously I said in the example, that I will delete the records with id 2 and 3, then If the condition in my controller, and my form in my view, work properly then I can add again the animal with id 2, and then in a new form add again the animal with id 3.

Thus, if my question was not understood very well or you thought that my function should add the record(s) simultaneously, you understood it wrong, because It's that not the function that I would like to do in the function.

Comment: You can, but isn't easier to create a new `order` column?

Comment: It's probably possible, but it won't be easy. Why does it matter _where_ the entry is placed in the table? Sounds like it may be a bad table design. Also, it's not usually a good idea to manually add 1 to the last id, it's much better to use auto-increment.

Comment: To echo others: "why?". This is not going to improve performance, so if you need your results ordered on a particular column, use the SQL `ORDER BY` statement. That's what it's for.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton. My table in the field `id` have already the attribute `autoincrement`

Comment: @M4uriXD Perfect, that means you should never manually increment the ID, and then you'll never have problems with data accidentally being duplicated or ignored because it has the same ID. Let MySQL do the work, does it really matter what order they are in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing to keep in mind when working with relational databases is that the `id` column is usually used to *relate* this data and as such it can and will appear in other tables. If you arbitrarily renumber things here, you're damaging those links and potentially scrambling up your data.

If ordering is important, create a column for that purpose, for example one called `position` or something similar. This one you can manipulate freely without concern about altering relations.

Generally your `id` value should be:

- Always populated (e.g. `NOT NULL`)
- Integer (e.g. `INT` or `BIGINT`)
- Set as your primary key (e.g. `PRIMARY KEY`)
- Generated automatically (e.g. `AUTO_INCREMENT`)
- Never changed, it's permanently assigned
- *Never recycled and used for another record*

Recycling `id` values is how you create enormous security problems. It's all too easy for a user to "inherit" all the data that came with an old user ID value you've recycled. The safest thing is to never, ever re-use these values.

They're just IDs. Forget about holes or lack of ordering. Any production database will end up with lots of interesting patterns there that are unavoidable, but it doesn't matter.

One exception to this is when creating seed databases. Here you can fuss over the ordering to get things arranged as you want because this is *before* you insert the data into the database.

At the end of the day you'll want to ensure that:

- These numbers don't overflow (e.g. `INT` keyed table at 2.1 billion)
- These numbers aren't exposed to users in a way that makes it possible to enumerate your table (e.g. ID value in a URL)

Just think of them as *internal* identifiers, like a serial number, and you'll be fine. In fact, MySQL now supports [`SERIAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) as a datatype for this reason, that's an alias for `BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE` which is a good default for systems designed in 2018.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really great answer from Tadman about the implications of your solution.

To give you an alternative to your own solution, you can do something like this....

First, create an `order` column, an int.

Them, instead of looking at the latest `id` value, do this...

```
$highestOrder = Animal::max('order');
```

And then 'up it'... :-)  Just an idea.

BTW: to give you more options, you can look directly in a table as well:

```
DB::table('animals')->max('order');
```

... but I would not do that in this case. The model class is the best 'gateway' to this information, not the DB facade directly.